# BarLegend using Function that uses Blend

Tags: bugs, color, legending

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I don't even know how to look for it.

I had this line of code that worked on a Notebook I wrote on *Mathematica* 9.0:

```
BarLegend[{colorf[#] &, {0, 30}}]
```

`colorf` is a Blend going from 0 to 30 (40 actually, but I don't think it really matters).

I just installed Mathematica 10.0, and it no longer works: the bar is all red (i.e. `colorf[0]`). Why is this happening?

edit: `colorf` is defined as follows

```
colorf=Blend[{{0, Red}, {20, Yellow}, {40, Green}}, Round[#, 0.1]] &;
```

Comment: `colorf = Blend[{Red, Blue}, #] &; BarLegend[{colorf, {0, 30}}]` works fine in V. 10.0.2. -- maybe it is the definition of `colorf` and using `colof[#] &`?

Comment: Could you provide all necessary code? @gwr's code works for me as well, so you should provide more information in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I just put it into the question

Comment: To me this looks like a bug in the scaling of `BarLegend`s with continuous gradients introduced in version 10 (I'm using v10.0.2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To me it looks like there is a bug in the Implementation of `BarLegend`. When the the number of contours increases there is not only a switch from discrete contours to a continuous gradient (this behavior is documented), but also a change in the scaling (that's the bug).

```
colorf = Blend[{{0, Red}, {20, Yellow}, {40, Green}}, Round[#, 0.1]] &;
BarLegend[{colorf[#] &, {0, 30}}, #] & /@ Range[15]
```

> [image]

One can use `Rescale` to fix this:

```
colorf2 = Blend[{{0, Red}, {20, Yellow}, {40, Green}}, 
            Round[Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {0, 40}], 0.1]] &;
BarLegend[{colorf2[#] &, {0, 30}}]
```

> [image]

But now one has to be aware that `BarLegend` with discrete contours is broken:

```
BarLegend[{colorf2[#] &, {0, 30}}, #] & /@ Range[15]
```

> [image]

Comment: Wow, impressive. Thanks.

However, the problem now is that yellow is 15, when it should be 20... Shall I just divide the parameter by 40?

Comment: Finally I solved the 15->yellow problem by doing `BarLegend[{colorf[#*30] &, {0, 30}}]`. Not the cleanest of solutions, but does the trick pretty well and doesn't need to modify the color function. I'm chosing this answer for completeness. Thanks to both!

Comment: @Rafael You can also use `BarLegend[{colorf2[# 30/40] &, {0, 30}}]`.

Answer (score 5):

`Blend` was modified in version 10. It appears that `Blend` is now scaled to {0, 1}.

```
colorf = Blend[{{0, Red}, {0.5, Yellow}, {1, Green}}, Round[#, 0.01]] &;

BarLegend[{colorf, {0, 30}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be no issue of `Blend`, but a bug in the scaling of `BarLegend`. See me answer and try `Graphics[Table[{colorf[x], Disk[{x, 0}]}, {x, 1, 40}]]`.

Comment: Interesting, both answers have good points but there seems to be indeed a bug as `BarLegend[{colorf, {0, 30}},n]` will give false answers for small n as shown in @Karsten 7's answer. BTW why is the `Round[#, 0.001]` needed?

Comment: @gwr In my opinion the `Round` is not needed, but it's in the code provided by the OP and I left it in the code to show that it's not the reason for the problem.

Comment: The purpose of `round`, as far as I remember, had to do with the main plot (to which this was but the legend). I think it was creating too many colors and thus leaking memory or something (there were thousands of points, nearly everyone with its own color)